# Format numeric values with preceding zero(0)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do I format numbers in JavaScript so that `1` becomes `01`?
My goal is to loop over every month of the year. If I hard code `_0` then `10,11` and become `010,011,012`.

```
for (var i = 2020; i < 2021; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
    var v = print(i + j)
    var dataset = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_4/MonthlyHistory/' + i + '_0' + j);
    var water = dataset.select('water')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but a better way to process images within a range of dates is to leverage earth engine's [server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) using [ee.imageCollection.filterDate](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-filterdate) instead of using a client-side loop.

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_4/MonthlyHistory')
.filterDate("2020-01-01", "2021-12-31")
.select("water")
```

If your goal is to perform an operation such as Map.addLayer, which is on the client-side (your browser), I recommend something like this:

```js
var visualization = {
  bands: ['water'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 2.0,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'fffcb8', '0905ff']
};

function addimgToMap(name){
  var img = ee.Image(name).clip(geometry);
  Map.addLayer(img, visualization, name)
}

var names = dataset.aggregate_array("system:id").getInfo()
names.map(addimgToMap)
```

Small demo here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/81195a4b01be32ebbcc53f82d6e0ef80

Comment: thank you for your response. I have one more query, what if I want to export this monthly data with unique name .

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Oliver. Chances are it's better for you to work with the image collection. However, if you do want to iterate the way you're doing, you can implement the padding like this:

```
for (var i = 2020; i < 2021; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
    var assetId = 'JRC/GSW1_4/MonthlyHistory/' + i + '_' + padWithZero(j, 2)
    print(assetId)
    var dataset = ee.Image(assetId);
    var water = dataset.select('water')
  }
}

function padWithZero(number, digits) {
  var num = number.toString()
  while (num.length < digits) num = "0" + num
  return num
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ab1c653dd06c7da6ee3867dec9e1c434

The pad function comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998822/9690663.